# Eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, orthogonality, tridiagonal-matrices

on page 13 of the paper [here](http://www.lboro.ac.uk/microsites/maths/research/preprints/papers10/10-20.pdf) there is a proof in theorem 4 that all eigenvalues of this tridiagonal matrix, which has strictly positive entries down the subdiagonals, are simple. Unfortunately, I don't get the argument. Apparently, it is almost immediate to the editor that $ker(J-\lambda I)$ must be one-dimensional for eigenvalues $\lambda$, where $J$ is the special tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: You've removed a bit of the context, actually: They require that the off-diagonal elements all be _positive_. (Which is rather natural, since otherwise the identity matrix is a big counter-example.)

Comment: yes, this is why I am talking about 'this' and not 'any' tridiagonal matrix, but your are right: It is good that you pointed this out. Do you understand their argument?

Comment: Not off the bat (though I should, since I've encountered this paper in my research before). My point was more that said context should be in the _question_ rather than requiring the reader to look it up in the paper, especially since it does seem to be a simple linear algebra question.

Comment: just out of curiosity, as you say that you know this paper. Do you know a fast way to actually show that the Whittaker Hill equation has this semifinite gap property?

Comment: sorry, I think it is better if we could join a room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17931/me-and-semiclassical

Comment: The link is not working and without it the question have no sense. Could anyone provide a reference or write the matrix?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the first row and last column from an irreducible $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix $T$, the resulting submatrix is triangular with non-zero diagonal entries. Hence it is invertible, and it follows that $\mathbb{rank}(T-\lambda I)$ is always at least $n-1$.

Comment: This seems to leave a gap: How does one show that a tridiagonal matrix with positive subdiagonal entries is irreducible? (I suppose it's a well-known result, but I don't recognize it off the top of my head.)

Comment: @semiclassical: By irreducible I meant only that the subdiagonal entrier were nonzero.

Comment: Ah. I was mislead by Wikipedia's citation of 'irreducible matrix' on its [irreducibility page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducibility_(mathematics)) which is rather different than that. Though I don't think irreducibility in your sense is necessarily enough: The paper cited by Tobias requires that the subdiagonals be strictly positive rather than nonzero. (I'll see if I can give a relevant counter-example in this vein.)

Comment: Quite forgot to follow up on this, but here's a counter-example: the matrix $$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is irreducible in your sense, and the submatrix upon deleting the first row and last column is indeed triangular (indeed diagonal) with nonzero diagonal entries. But the characteristic polynomial $\det(T-\lambda I)=-\lambda^3$ has zero as a triple-root, and so this eigenvalue is not simple.

Comment: @semiclassical: For me a tridiagonal matrix has its off-diagonal entries non-negative. This is a common convention.

Comment: Maybe so, but I don't see that condition used at all in your answer. Moreover, if I look at the $T$ in my previous comment, I would again point out: if I delete the first row and last column, the remaining matrix is just the $2\times 2$ identity and so is invertible. But this $T$ doesn't have simple eigenvalues. So unless you're appealing to more than just "deleting the upper row and the RH column gives an invertible matrix", I really don't see how this can be a valid proof.

Comment: No, I am appealing to the fact that, for tridiagonal matrices (as described), the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal. One reason is that "my" tridiagonal matrices are similar to symmetric matrices.

Comment: Ok. Then my question is: _Why isn't that context in your answer?_

Comment: Because the context I was working in was the context the paper cited by the OP.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil could you again explain why this matrix is invertible then?