# If an upper bidiagonal matrix has a repeated singular value, it must have a zero on its diagonal or superdiagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have a question that mentioned in the book "Matrix Computations" by Golub and van Loan.
"Show that if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an upper bidiagonal matrix having a repeated singular value, then $A$ must have a zero on its diagonal or superdiagonal."

I have proved this question is right for an upper bidiagonal matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. But I can not prove it for general upper bidiagonal matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: What does this have to do with SVD?

Comment: I don't understand your question correctly?

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196525/ Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of having an answer, note that if all diagonal and superdiagonal elements of $A$ are nonzero, then $A^TA$ would be a symmetric tridiagonal matrix with nonzero super/sub-diagonal entries. It is known that such a matrix must have distinct eigenvalues (see [the proof by Algebraic Pavel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/521352/1551) or [the answer by Chris Godsil](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977530) in two other threads). It follows that $A$ has distinct singular values.